# How to add a download button on the controller of multiple plyr.io audio player?

Tags: jquery, plyr

I'm building an audio collection page where you can preview the audio and download it if you want. I have already built the multiple audio players but I'm not sure how to add the download button to the controls. I also want to remove the cog icon and replace it with the download icon.

Here's the [codepen link](https://codepen.io/ableslayer/pen/NWWKzdg)

Here's the script:

```
  const players = Plyr.setup('.js-player');
  window.player = player;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can customize the controls with the following:

```
var controls =
[  
  'play',
  'progress',
  'duration',
  'mute',
  'volume',
  'download',
];

const players = Plyr.setup('.js-player', { controls });

window.player = player;
```

You can check [here](https://github.com/sampotts/plyr/blob/master/controls.md) for more information.